# How can I render a remote image with php?

Tags: php, image, header, http-headers

Here's a jpg: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFN0.jpg`

[image: stackoverflow logo jpg]

Let's say I'd like this rendered from `/img.php?file_name=PIFN0.jpg`

Here's how I'm trying to make this work:

**/sample.php**

```
<p>Here's my image:</p>
<img src="/img.php?file_name=PIFN0.jpg">
```

**/img.php**

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/' . $_GET['file_name'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($url);
?>
```

I would expect `/sample.php` to show the image.  But this doesn't work.  All I get is a broken image.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `imagecreatefromjpeg`:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/' . $_GET['file_name'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
?>
```

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Huh - I didn't realize imagecreatefromjpeg() and its ilk supported the fopen() wrappers.

Comment: Yep :) cool stuff - I guess someone had to set it up eventually

Comment: To the OP: Of course, this doesn't guarantee that the server on which the image resides will actually _allow_ you to download it via PHP and re-serve it.

Comment: what if you have a mix of jpg ng anf gifs?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an working example:

```
<?php
function img_create($filename, $mime_type) 
{  
  $content = file_get_contents($filename);
  $base64   = base64_encode($content); 
  return ('data:' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>

<img src="<?php print img_create('http://tuxpaint.org/stamps/stamps/animals/birds/cartoon/tux.png','image/png'); ?>" alt="random logo" />
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use the GD functions:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/' . $_GET['file_name'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFN0.jpg";
$imgContents = file_get_contents($url);
$image = @imagecreatefromstring($imgContents);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($_GET['id']);
```

but in the new server, only can read the local images, the remote images is error.