# Issue while trying to display a remote image (GET php) - corrupt/empty image

Tags: php, get

I'd like to display some remote images from a php url with a GET method (3 parameters: Key, ImageID, Size).
E.g: http://www.example.com/getImage?Key=thekey&ImageId=2&Size=1

I followed this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629513 (replacing the content-type with jpeg), tried with a random jpeg image on the net and it worked.

However, when I try this method with my php url: the file is corrupted.

```
<?php
function img_create($filename, $mime_type)
{
  $content = file_get_contents($filename);
  $base64   = base64_encode($content);
  return ('data:' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>
<img src="<?php print img_create('http://www.example.com/getImage?Key=thekey&ImageId=2&Size=1','image/jpeg'); ?>" alt="random logo" />
```

Any idea..?

Comment: What is the html output? Do you actually get a base64 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

function img_create($filename, $mime_type) { 
   $content = file_get_contents($filename); 
   $base64   = base64_encode($content);
   $src_string = 'data:'.$mime_type.';base64,'.$base64;
   echo $src_string;
}
?>

<img src="<?php img_create('http://www.example.com/getImage?Key=thekey&ImageId=2&Size=1','image/jpeg'); ?>" alt="random logo" />
```

Comment: Many thanks !

That was missing :
   $src_string = 'data:'.$mime_type.';base64,'.$base64;
   echo $src_string;

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Works fine Just, I think there is some Issue with Your image URl

```
<?php
```

function img_create($filename, $mime_type)
{

$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$base64   = base64_encode($content);

return ('data:' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . $base64);

}

?>

```
<img src="<?php print img_create('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497316730643-415fac54a2af?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80','image/jpeg'); ?>" alt="random logo" />
```